# How can make gvim identify "/" in the search pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to search and delete lines containing the pattern `/old/` I am using the following command `:g/\/old\//d`. The gvim doesn't recognize the backslash used to treat the forward slash as it is. How can I make it identify the forward slash as it is?

Thanks,
Bharadwaj

Comment: `g%/old/%%d` . You can use any punctualtion as delimiter

Comment: Thanks a lot.  g%/old/%d worked. So the idea is to use % in the place of forward slash to do the search operations. Let me know if my understanding is correct. Thanks

Comment: You're not limited to `%`. Whatever character follows the command will be used as delimiter, within reason. Try `!` or `#` too.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)